# SQL Server "two way" unique/primary key for 2 columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

How can I make 2 columns unique so that (A,B) == (B,A).

For example a table with two columns UserId and FriendId.

If theres a row with values (1,2) and someone attempts to enter a row (2,1) then that wouldn't be allowed.

Comment: Every time you insert  AB, insert BA along with it

Comment: is this a common and used practice in development? it will make the table take double the storage space.

Comment: Double shmubble. It's when things grow exponentially that you have to start to worry. Common? Dunno. I use it.

Comment: Yes, it's common to denote a double relationship, often in an association table though (a product to a related product, for example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can place a trigger that will check if the opposite exists and if so then undo the transaction.